# ASP.net core2.0 is compiling but not publishing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, publish, publishing, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to publish a `.net core 2.0` website, It's compiling with no errors but throwing :

```
"Could not find file PATH\netcoreapp2.0\PATH.AssemblyInfo.cs"
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments here:

https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6649

I followed this sequence to catch the hidden error:

dotnet restore -> No errors

dotnet build -c debug -> No errors

dotnet publish -c debug -> Error Appeared

For me it was because of using `@<text>` inside a `Kendo().Grid` template